# Postfix++ Code in Javascript Bug in response

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this code in javascript, works well but there is a bug in the response instead to get

```
Enter a Postfix++ expression:A 5 = B 3 = A B *

Result: 15
{ A: 5, B: 3 }
```

i get

```
Enter a Postfix++ expression:A 5 = B 3 = A B *

Result: B
{ A: 5, B: 3 }
```

This is the code below:

```
    class PostfixInterpreter {
  constructor() {
    this.tokenStack = [];
    this.symbolTable = {};
  }

processToken(token) {
  if (this.isVariable(token)) {
    this.tokenStack.push(token);
  } else if (this.isValue(token)) {
    this.tokenStack.push(parseFloat(token));
  } else if (token === '=') {
    const value = this.tokenStack.pop();
    const variable = this.tokenStack.pop();
    this.symbolTable[variable] = value;
  }
}

evaluatePostfix(expression) {
  const tokens = expression.split(' ');
  for (const token of tokens) {
    this.processToken(token);
  }

  // Ensure the stack contains only the final result
  const result = this.tokenStack.pop();

  // Clear the stack before printing the result
  this.tokenStack = [];

  console.log("Result:", result);
  return result;
}



  isVariable(token) {
    return /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(token);
  }

  isValue(token) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(token));
  }
}

// Example usage with user input:
const postfixInterpreter = new PostfixInterpreter();
const expression = prompt("Enter a Postfix++ expression:");
postfixInterpreter.evaluatePostfix(expression);
console.log(postfixInterpreter.symbolTable);
```

I tried to debug it but i failed couldnt find the part where the bug happens. Thank you in advance if you help me.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that handles the `*` not multiplies the two variables your creating. You need to implement that logic into your parser.